# How does liferay set post login landing page from control panel

Tags: liferay

Can someone tell me the class where liferay sets the default landing page.

Admin > Control Panel > Portal Settings set Default Landing Page to /landing-page

I tries to follow the control panel URL and landed on the com.liferay.portlet.portalsettings.action.EditCompanyAction,
but there values for the default landing page are not set. 
Is there anything that I missed??

Comment: `portal-impl\src\com\liferay\portal\events\DefaultLandingPageAction.java` is the class which uses Default Landing page which is set in Control Panel > Portal Settings, Is that what you are looking for or something else?

Comment: Hey Pankaj,
This class is loading the property from PropsUtil. If I am right this is the property loaded from the properties file. I want to know where the liferay is loading the value from the text box (_130_settings--default.landing.page.path--).

Comment: Danish, `PrefsPropsUtil.getString(companyId,PropsKeys.DEFAULT_LANDING_PAGE_PATH)` , this does not get value from property file but from database(`portalpreferences` table)

Comment: Thanks Pankaj for the clarification on that,
But still the question remains the same where does liferay fetches the value from the text box and sets it into the portalpreferences .

Comment: If you are asking about how that value gets stored then look at CompanyServiceUtil.updateCompany call in EditCompanyAction, here last parameter properties gets every properties which has settings-- as prefix. does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks a lot pankaj...
You really cleared that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at updateCompany method of EditCompanyAction and CompanyServiceImpl.

In EditCompanyAction, all portal settings related properties are fetched by code

```
UnicodeProperties properties = PropertiesParamUtil.getProperties(
           actionRequest, "settings--");
```

And In `CompanyServiceImpl.updateCompany` method you will find

```
 updatePreferences(company.getCompanyId(), properties);
```

call which will save portal settings related properties to `portalpreferecences` table.